# HTTPWebResponse Failed to stream the response when passing "Combination Of Special characters" as password in Parameters

Tags: c#, windows

Working Scenario

When Passing first parameter "strPostData" (Not contain special characters in password) as below xml request means works fine and StreamReader providing the response as well & variable "strResult" loaded successfully.. "Request=janajana"

NOT Working Scenario

But when user password contains "special characters" in first parameter "strPostData" means, StreamReader failed to provide the response & variable "strResult" not loaded successfully.. `"Request=<request><Username>jana</Username><Password>jana!@#$%^&*()</Password></request>"`
When passing password with combination of "special characters" when HTTPWebResponse failed & Streamreader also gets failed..

I have tried with Stream object statement with ..

```
//string tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); &
```

Read Buffer code change 
    //Int32 count = await streamRead.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, 256); but not works ,,, please guide me anyone

```
public string[] GetResponseWebAPI(string strPostData, string strUrl)
{            
string[] arrReturn = new string[3];
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(strPostData);
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
myRequest.Timeout = 25000;// 25s
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new 
System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
(AcceptAllCertifications);
Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
newStream.Close();
myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
WebHeaderCollection webHeader = myHttpWebResponse.Headers;
arrReturn[0] = webHeader["Statuscode"];
arrReturn[1] = webHeader["Statusmessage"];                
Stream streamResponse = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
Char[] readBuffer = new Char[256];
int count = streamRead.Read(readBuffer,0, 256);
string strResult = string.Empty;
while (count > 0)
{
strResult += new String(readBuffer,0, count);
count = streamRead.Read(readBuffer,0, 256);
}
arrReturn[2] = strResult;
streamRead.Close();
streamResponse.Close();
myHttpWebResponse.Close();           
return arrReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in

```
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

So, from this line you are saying that content is URL-encoded and should be [escaped](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).
So I assume, as a quick fix you could change

```
byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(strPostData);
```

to

```
byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(WebUtility.UrlEncode(strPostData));
```

or something.

But I do believe this intention could be expressed better. So consider using HttpClient and FormUrlEncodedContent:

```
    public string[] GetResponseWebAPI(string strPostData, string strUrl)
    {
        string[] arrReturn = new string[3];

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        using (var content =
            new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Request", strPostData)}))
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25);
            var response = client.PostAsync(strUrl, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            arrReturn[0] = response.Headers.GetValues("Statuscode").FirstOrDefault();
            arrReturn[1] = response.Headers.GetValues("Statusmessage").FirstOrDefault();
            arrReturn[2] = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        return arrReturn;
    }
```

Comment: "new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Request", strPostData)}" is based on sample from original question.

Comment: Elitery Thanks for your suggestion .. for above two suggestions I m getting Status Code as "11" and Status Message as "Request Not Valid"  ..Still not works ..

Comment: Well, we have to figure out what goes wrong here. Do you have any information on what requests server accepts? Can you make post via postman or something to know exactly what is needed?